# directory is copied to minikube but not file inside it

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

This is the directory on the host:

```
├── deploy.yaml
└── foobar
    └── foo.sh
```

and the content of deploy.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foobar-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foobar-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foobar-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: foobar-container
          image: nginx
          #command: ["sh", "-c", ""/foobar/foo.sh""] 
          volumeMounts:
            - name: foobar-volume
              mountPath: /foobar
      volumes:
        - name: foobar-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/n/projects/minikube-test/foobar
```

When I exec into the container, I see foobar directory, but not foo.sh.

```
k exec -it foobar-deployment-8459bf6d8f-mlprq -- ls -lart foobar
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 02:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 17 03:14 ..
```

What am I missing? Thank you

Comment: The `hostPath:` volume mounts content from whichever node the container happens to be running on; it won't mount consistent content if there are multiple replicas runing on multiple nodes.  Do you mean to copy this shell script into a custom Docker image?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have only one node. It eventually worked for me as I posted below, when I mounted host directory in Minikube, and then set `hostPath.path` to location in Minikube, e.g. "/mnt/foobar" while leaving `volumeMounts.mountPath` unchanged, e.g. "foobar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:
First, mounted host directory to a location on the VM:

```
minikube mount /home/n/projects/minikube-test/foobar:/mnt1/foobar
```

Next, modified deploy.yaml file:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: foobar-volume
              mountPath: /foobar
      volumes:
        - name: foobar-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt1/foobar
```